# Не переведены подсказки в сниппете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, сниппеты

В сниппете не переведены подсказки для элементов

Use BabelJS / ES2015 (название элемента так же не переведено)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для элемента "Скрыть код по уполчанию" (опечатка в названии элемента)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]